# Is there a way to access the keys from the values?

Tags: ruby, hash, key

If I type something like:

```
example = {"Example_Key" => "Example_Value"}
example["Example_Key"]
```

the interpreter will return `"Example_Value"`, which is the value. Is there a way to enter a value and get the key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is :

```
example = {"Example_Key" => "Example_Value"}
example.key "Example_Value" # => "Example_Key"
```

Check out the documentation [`Hash#key`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-key)

> Returns the **key** of an occurrence of a given **value**. If the **value** is not found, returns `nil`.

Comment: Note that a) it returns "an occurrence", not "the occurrence" or "all occurrences" (there can be more than one) and b) it has to search for the key, i.e. it is O(n). If you frequently need to look up in both directions, you should not use a map but a bimap/bidimap.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a hash that works the other way:

```
inverted = example.invert # => {"Example_Value"=>"Example_Key"}
inverted["Example_Value"] # => "Example_Key"
```